# Quickbooks Desktop Web Connector can I make an inventory adjustment based on item's id or other attribute.?

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

I have a program that can adjust quickbooks item/product on hand quantity through making an inventoryAdjustment. Currently i can only adjust the inventory by matching the item name. is there any other attribute i can use (item serial#, item id) to query and update the item on hand quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the QuickBooks OSR for reference on what fields can be queried:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

You can query items by:

- ListID
- Name
- FullName

And when referring to items during an Inventory Adjustment, you can refer to them by either:

- ListID
- FullName

If you want to query by anything else, you need to query the entire item list and filter it down on your end with your own code.